# How do I use CustomEventArgs in my handler which I assign to UIButton.TouchUpInside?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uibutton, xamarin.ios

I'm using reusable cells in a UICollectionView. As such I need to subscribe and unsubscribe eventhandlers for buttons in each cell to avoid multiple event fires. As I understand it, I could easily pass parameters to the handler with a Lambda Expression, but that would mean no unsubscribing.

So I've created a class for CustomEventArgs:

```
internal class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DetailCell Cell {get; private set; }

    public int Position { get; private set; }

    public CustomEventArgs(DetailCell cell, int position)
    {
        this.Cell = cell;
        this.Position = position;
    }
}
```

And I try to subscribe to this once the cell is created in the following override:

```
public override void WillDisplayCell(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = cell as DetailCell;
        if (cell != null)
        {
            var eventArgs = new CustomEventArgs(cell, (int)indexPath.Item);
            cell.EditButton.TouchUpInside += OnEditClicked(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting a compile error saying that the void OnEditClicked method can't be converted to System.EventHandler. I try to set the return type of OnEditClicked to EventHandler but then I'm not exactly sure that this is correct, and if it is, I'm not sure what I'd return.

I'm pretty sure there is a gap in my knowledge, and that there is an easy fix here. Is it possible to subscribe to TouchUpInside the way that I'm doing, and if so, what am I missing to do so?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but the way you are adding your event handler isn't working. The code should look like: `cell.EditButton.TouchUpInside += OnEditClicked;`. That way it will compile again. Inside the OnEditClicked method you can cast the sender to DetailCell. So instead of writing a custom EventArgs you should modify your custom cell.